# virt-sysprep - Is it possible to use with LVM & LUKS?

Tags: kvm, virsh

I am trying to make a template VM using virt-sysprep. The host is CentOS 7, and the guests are CentOS 7 in LVM partitions (not RAW or qcow image files). The guest I'm working with has LUKS full disk encryption, set up at install time. When I run virt-sysprep with -v, I can see that it seems to recognize the basic disk structure in the guest, and it lists what appears to be all entries under /dev. However, it fails with an error:

```
virt-sysprep: error: no operating systems were found in the guest image
```

The command I'm trying is:

```
virt-sysprep -d base1 --hostname basetest.mydomain.com --echo-keys --keys-from-stdin
```

Has anyone managed to get virt-sysprep to work with a LUKS encrypted guest on LVM?

Comment: I don't think it will ever work, precisely because the guest is encrypted. (Which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense; normally you encrypt the host storage.)

Comment: In the man page there is a --key option, which allows you to put a LUKS passphrase in the command. The --keys-from-stdin seems to allow you to be prompted for the key instead, but I have not been able to get that aspect to work. I'm going to try getting it to work with --keys instead.

Comment: Looking further into it, It seems that the --key option is missing from newer versions of virt-sysprep, so maybe the developer gave up on LUKS in the guests.